# change php variable value in index.php with ajax and without reloading the page

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

I need to load $message1 and $message2 back into index.php when the corresponding anchors are clicked, with ajax, so that the new values are displayed in index.php without the page resfreshing. this code functions as is, I just can't figure out how to do this, could anybody help me figure out how? I've never written this type of script before and have gotten a little advice on how to do it but I'm still very confused.

this is my general.js file

```
$(".vote").click(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var name = $(this).attr("name");
var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");
var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;
var parent = $(this);

if(name=='up')
{
   $(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "up.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
         parent.html(html);
      }
   });
}
else
{
   $(this).fadeIn(200).html('');
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "down.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
         parent.html(html);
      }
   });
 }
 });
```

here is the html from my index.php

```
 <?php

 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogData ORDER BY id DESC");
 $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mod(mes_id,2) = 0 ORDER BY mes_id DESC");
 $sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE mod(mes_id,2) = 1 ORDER BY mes_id DESC");

 $count_variable = 0;

    while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))AND($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2))AND($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql3)) ){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $content = $row['content'];
        $category = $row['category'];
        $podcast = $row['podcast'];
        $datetime = $row['datetime'];

        $message1=$row2['msg'];
        $mes_id1=$row2['mes_id'];
        $totalvotes1=$row2['totalvotes'];

        $message2=$row3['msg'];
        $mes_id2=$row3['mes_id'];
        $totalvotes2=$row3['totalvotes'];


    ?>

<table class="content">
 <tr>
 <td>


 <div id="main">
 <div id="left">
 <span class='up'><a href="" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a></span><br />
 <?php echo $totalvotes1; ?><br />
 </div>
 <div id="message">
 <?php echo $message1; ?>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
 <div id="main">
 <div id="right">
 <br />
 <?php echo $totalvotes2; ?><br />
 <span class='down'><a href="" class="vote" name="down" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="down.png" alt="Down" /></a></span>
 </div>
 <div id="message">
 <?php echo $message2; ?>
 </div>
 <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
 </td>
 </tr>
 </table>

 <?php
  }
  ?>
```

and here is my up.php file

```
 <?php

 session_start();
 include("config.php");

 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

 $mes_id1 = $_POST['key1'];
 $mes_id2 = $_POST['key2'];
 $totalvotes1 = $_POST['key3'];

 $ip_sql=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$mes_id1' and ip_add='$ip'");
 $count=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql);

 $ip_sql2=mysql_query("select ip_add from Voting_IP where mes_id_fk='$mes_id2' and ip_add='$ip'");
 $count2=mysql_num_rows($ip_sql2);

 // if the user has already voted, execute script
 if($count==0 && $count2!=0)
 {
 $sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes+1  where mes_id='$mes_id1'";
 mysql_query( $sql);

 $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$mes_id1','$ip')";
 mysql_query( $sql_in);

 $sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes-1  where mes_id='$mes_id2'";
 mysql_query( $sql);

 $sql_in = "DELETE FROM Voting_IP WHERE mes_id_fk='$mes_id2'";
 mysql_query( $sql_in);


 // if the user has not voted, execute script
 }
 else if($count==0 && count2==0)
 {
$sql = "update Messages set totalvotes=totalvotes+1  where mes_id='$mes_id1'";
 mysql_query( $sql);

 $sql_in = "insert into Voting_IP (mes_id_fk,ip_add) values ('$mes_id1','$ip')";
 mysql_query( $sql_in);

 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Quick comment, look here: 
`var eData = $(this).attr("data-options");`
`var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&' + eData ;` You are sending an improper data string with Ajax.. ever value needs to have 'key=value' and those must be separated with '&'. `eData` doesn't have a key here.

Comment: Where did you define `$message1` and `$message2`?

Comment: sorry... ill post that up top, let me edit it

Comment: i just posted the rest of the index.php where I declared the variables

Comment: @TheWeirdNerd the script works right now without doing that... the values are carried over and changed in my DB. or are you saying that changing the script you posted will make it function so that it displays back into index.php without reloading....?

Comment: Hold on, I didn't realize you posted only part of index.php. What is the value of `$(this).attr("data-options");`? There is a specific format for ajax data when you send it to the server so it can be retrieved with `$_POST[]`. I'm just not sure you are doing that correctly.

Comment: its posted in the index.php part up there, in the table in the html. it's sent with this anchor here.
<a href="" class="vote" name="up" data-options="key1=<?php echo $mes_id1;?>&key2=<?php echo $mes_id2;?>"><img src="up.png" alt="Down" /></a>

Comment: I know I need to send the $messsage1 and $message2 key's in the data-options on my anchor in index.php but how would I get the new values of the $message1 and $message2 variables to be displayed in index.php after this all executes...?

Comment: Ok I see what you're doing. Geeze, it would be a good idea to organize this a little more. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: sorry man :( thanks for helping. new to stackflow, and relatively new to php and ajax

Comment: and by the way, the down.php file is the same as up.php file... just with opposite placement of the variables.... didn't think I needed to include that up top

Comment: You need to rethink how you organize your web pages, you don't need to separate them for that. While it's true that it is good practice to have one purpose for one function (to keep things simple) it's not so organized to have many webpages with lots of redundant functions. Try to create common functions and as few handler pages as would make logical sense. I myself use Ajax a lot and for one particular web site I only have one handler page. I just keep it organized with variables and switches to control the flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first Ajax request, for example, you have set the `url` to `up.php`

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "up.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html){
         parent.html(html);
      }
   });
```

That means that you'll be retrieving data from `up.php`. The way that an Ajax request works is that ANY data displayed on the php page, after it's done loading, will be returned as a string to the page that sent the Ajax request.

In your up.php page, you have not put any echo statements or any html code. Thus there is no data in your success function being returned. Which makes `parent.html(html)` redundant.

You also cannot update variables on one php page from an Ajax request like you have specified. What you need to do is update the HTML data, or build the `up.php` page so that it returns a variable which you want to set to a Javascript variable in your success function....

i.e.

In up.php you must do the sql statement again, to retrieve the data that you want to change $message to and then echo that...

More or less like this: (very generalized I know)

```
$data = $_POST['ajaxRequestData'];
//do something with the data to create a new SQL statement

//do the sql statement and extract the value of $message that you're looking for
//THEN****
echo $message;
```

Next in your Ajax success function...

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "up.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         //here data will be equal to the value that you echoed in the up.php page.
         //do whatever you want to do with it... You will not have access to the php variable on this page with Javascript. 
         //Server sided languages like PHP do not talk directly with client sided languages like Javascript except with Ajax.

         updateMessage(data); //what I would do is create a function to send the variable to, to perform the necessary modifications to update your webpage.
      }
});
//Note that as soon as the success function ends, the returned data is no longer available to you 
//so you must pass it to a function (or a global variable) to be able to use it.
```

Comment: i edited the script and posted where i decalre the variables in index.php and all the variables are being defined and manipulated correctly right now with my php and in my database. the only issue is displaying them back into index.php

Comment: so are you saying in my up.php file, I need to declare $eData = $_POST['eData']; and then post the $eData variable in my anchor?

Comment: Thank you! ok so, $message1 = 1 and then up.php is executed and now $message1 = 2, and if I implement this script correctly it should be able to display that value back into the html in my index.php file...?

Comment: You cannot update `$message1` with an Ajax request. Forget about trying to update the PHP variable. Instead update the `div` with the id `message` with a variable returned from an Ajax request.

Comment: Any more questions? Also if you managed to figure out your problem based on my answer, it would be nice to mark as an answer. Just sayin.

Comment: ok, I think I understand now. but then how do make the old value leave the display when the new one loads in....

Comment: Quick note. I just noticed you're using the same id for more than one div. Id's MUST be unique to only one element, in your case above, it's better you use classes instead, or change the id's to `<div id='message1'>` and `<div id='message2'>`. Since the text you want to change is contained in those divs, you just need to update the contents of the divs with the data retrieved from the ajax request. I.e. in the success function. `success: function(data) { $('#message1').text(data); }`

Comment: so, I can't set a specific id to the div because then every time the javascript is executed it only displays the new content in the div in the very top table in my query in index.php, instead of the corresponding div. i got everything else to work so far though.... just going to need to figure out how to have a specific id here, success: function(data) { $('#message1').text(data); } because I have a query that echos a table and there will be about 50 div's with the same id

Comment: Then use a class i.e. `$('.message')` you just need to figure out the proper selectors to get what you want. You'll figure it out and become a better programmer.